# How to make next list item start after the image end in floating paragraph?

Tags: html

I am trying to make an ordered list which includes: a floating picture with link and some text next to it.
I am able to add the text next to the floating picture/link but the next item in list runs up to where the text ends. i.e. next to the picture.

How may I set the next list item to only start where the link/image/text ends ends?

I have tried almost everything I could think up. Such as setting a border, removing the `<ol>` tag which I really don't want to remove for SEO.

```html
<ol>
  <li>
    <p><strong><a href="https://amzn.to/2DKOgiv" target="_blank">Stocks to Riches – Parag Parikh</a></strong></p>
    <div>
      <p style="float: left;">
        <a href="https://www.amazon.in/Stocks-Riches-Insights-Investor-Behaviour/dp/0070597715/ref=as_li_ss_il?dchild=1&keywords=Stocks+to+Riches&qid=1594804652&sr=8-1&linkCode=li2&tag=coffeeandserv-21&linkId=e9b697acda21ca9f0bf6a4aacf5aa7bd&language=en_IN"
          target="_blank"><img border="0" src="//ws-in.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/q?_encoding=UTF8&ASIN=0070597715&Format=_SL160_&ID=AsinImage&MarketPlace=IN&ServiceVersion=20070822&WS=1&tag=coffeeandserv-21&language=en_IN"></a><img src="https://ir-in.amazon-adsystem.com/e/ir?t=coffeeandserv-21&language=en_IN&l=li2&o=31&a=0070597715"
          width="1" height="1" border="0" alt="" style="border:none !important; margin:0px !important;" /></p>
      <p>Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <!--<a href="https://www.amazon.in/Stocks-Riches-Insights-Investor-Behaviour/dp/0070597715/ref=as_li_ss_il?dchild=1&keywords=Stocks+to+Riches&qid=1594804652&sr=8-1&linkCode=li1&tag=coffeeandserv-21&linkId=4cff84be52969788f9b4c1452bf8d979&language=en_IN" target="_blank"><img border="0" src="//ws-in.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/q?_encoding=UTF8&ASIN=0070597715&Format=_SL110_&ID=AsinImage&MarketPlace=IN&ServiceVersion=20070822&WS=1&tag=coffeeandserv-21&language=en_IN" ></a><img src="https://ir-in.amazon-adsystem.com/e/ir?t=coffeeandserv-21&language=en_IN&l=li1&o=31&a=0070597715" width="1" height="1" border="0" alt="" style="border:none !important; margin:0px !important;" />-->

  <li><strong><a href="https://amzn.to/2OwUioR" target="_blank">Value Investing And Behavioral Finance -  Parag Parikh</a></strong><br>
    <a href="https://www.amazon.in/VALUE-INVESTING-BEHAVIORAL-FINANCE-PARIKH-ebook/dp/B078FH45GW/ref=as_li_ss_il?dchild=1&keywords=Value+Investing+And+Behavioral+Finance&qid=1594804861&sr=8-3&linkCode=li1&tag=coffeeandserv-21&linkId=a6a7369ec3af93ed5f3a9940447d16b6&language=en_IN"
      target="_blank"><img border="0" src="//ws-in.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/q?_encoding=UTF8&ASIN=B078FH45GW&Format=_SL110_&ID=AsinImage&MarketPlace=IN&ServiceVersion=20070822&WS=1&tag=coffeeandserv-21&language=en_IN"></a><img src="https://ir-in.amazon-adsystem.com/e/ir?t=coffeeandserv-21&language=en_IN&l=li1&o=31&a=B078FH45GW"
      width="1" height="1" border="0" alt="" style="border:none !important; margin:0px !important;" />
  </li>
</ol>
```

I have seen a `css` solution to it here. But wondering if there is something which can be done using html?

Comment: Have you tried `overflow:auto;` for parent element of floats? Also I do not understand what do you mean by html solution, you already have style declaration in elements. I assume you may use tables for pure html solution

Comment: @SergiyT. Ah I didn't realise `style` is equal to `css`. I am very new to html and css. I tried the `overflow:auto;` it does solve the next list element item problem but now the text instead of being next to the floating element is after the picture.

Comment: I expanded my comment into answer. You may check if it is the answer you were looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add `overflow:auto;` for parent element of floated divs. This will make parent element occupy as much vertical space as floated childs.

```html
<ol>
  <li>
    <p><strong><a href="https://amzn.to/2DKOgiv" target="_blank">Stocks to Riches – Parag Parikh</a></strong></p>
    <div style="overflow:auto;">
      <p style="float: left;">
        <a href="https://www.amazon.in/Stocks-Riches-Insights-Investor-Behaviour/dp/0070597715/ref=as_li_ss_il?dchild=1&keywords=Stocks+to+Riches&qid=1594804652&sr=8-1&linkCode=li2&tag=coffeeandserv-21&linkId=e9b697acda21ca9f0bf6a4aacf5aa7bd&language=en_IN"
          target="_blank"><img border="0" src="//ws-in.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/q?_encoding=UTF8&ASIN=0070597715&Format=_SL160_&ID=AsinImage&MarketPlace=IN&ServiceVersion=20070822&WS=1&tag=coffeeandserv-21&language=en_IN"></a><img src="https://ir-in.amazon-adsystem.com/e/ir?t=coffeeandserv-21&language=en_IN&l=li2&o=31&a=0070597715"
          width="1" height="1" border="0" alt="" style="border:none !important; margin:0px !important;" /></p>
      <p>Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text Text</p>
    </div>
  </li>

  <!--<a href="https://www.amazon.in/Stocks-Riches-Insights-Investor-Behaviour/dp/0070597715/ref=as_li_ss_il?dchild=1&keywords=Stocks+to+Riches&qid=1594804652&sr=8-1&linkCode=li1&tag=coffeeandserv-21&linkId=4cff84be52969788f9b4c1452bf8d979&language=en_IN" target="_blank"><img border="0" src="//ws-in.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/q?_encoding=UTF8&ASIN=0070597715&Format=_SL110_&ID=AsinImage&MarketPlace=IN&ServiceVersion=20070822&WS=1&tag=coffeeandserv-21&language=en_IN" ></a><img src="https://ir-in.amazon-adsystem.com/e/ir?t=coffeeandserv-21&language=en_IN&l=li1&o=31&a=0070597715" width="1" height="1" border="0" alt="" style="border:none !important; margin:0px !important;" />-->

  <li><strong><a href="https://amzn.to/2OwUioR" target="_blank">Value Investing And Behavioral Finance -  Parag Parikh</a></strong><br>
    <div style="overflow:auto;">
        <a href="https://www.amazon.in/VALUE-INVESTING-BEHAVIORAL-FINANCE-PARIKH-ebook/dp/B078FH45GW/ref=as_li_ss_il?dchild=1&keywords=Value+Investing+And+Behavioral+Finance&qid=1594804861&sr=8-3&linkCode=li1&tag=coffeeandserv-21&linkId=a6a7369ec3af93ed5f3a9940447d16b6&language=en_IN"
      target="_blank"><img border="0" src="//ws-in.amazon-adsystem.com/widgets/q?_encoding=UTF8&ASIN=B078FH45GW&Format=_SL110_&ID=AsinImage&MarketPlace=IN&ServiceVersion=20070822&WS=1&tag=coffeeandserv-21&language=en_IN"></a>

        <img src="https://ir-in.amazon-adsystem.com/e/ir?t=coffeeandserv-21&language=en_IN&l=li1&o=31&a=B078FH45GW"
      width="1" height="1" border="0" alt="" style="border:none !important; margin:0px !important;" />
    </div>
  </li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Thanks, I was adding the `style="overflow:auto"` at the wrong point.